# SPARQL.ORG doesn't work with long queries

Tags: sparql

I use [sparql.org](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html) to format my queries. It works with small queries, but with long ones, the page would just show that spinner looping and after 4 or 5 minutes, i get an answer such as "no response from server" (not exactly the same error message but more or less)

my queries with the comments is 160 line long, and without comment about 130 lines.

I need to know if there is another tool (or website) to format my sparql query please.

#### Update

This is the error:

[image]

Comment: If you're already running jena locally, you can just format and print the query locally.  Sparql.org is just running (a slightly older version of) jena.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I tried this: `Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryTemplate);
  System.out.println(query.toString());` The result is a formatted query, but without *any* comment, in this case, i would need to re add the comments everytime i edit the query manually, would you suggest a slightly better option please ?

Comment: I don't think sparql.org preserves comments either, does it? But is there some reason to not just format them nicely as you're writing them?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor no both of they don't preserve the comments, maybe another tool or website could help here?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor what is `sine` mean ?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but do note that since the are no block comments, formatting with comments is harder.  If you put a comment someplace where the formatter wants to put something afterward, the formatter can't turnstiles the way it wants to, and you not get inconsistent output.

Comment: It was a phone auto correct for "some".

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor okay i get you, no problem at least we get a formatted query and i will add the comments manually, thanks as always, if you prefer write an answer please

Comment: The problem is how the client is sending the request to sparql.org. It seems to be a truncated request.

Comment: Comments are not preserved -  sparql.org parses the query and reprints it and that does not include comments.